# Space between text and superscript too little with CMU Serif font

Tags: fonts, spacing, citing, superscripts, computer-modern

I'm having some trouble with the spacing between text and superscript in citations. 
With Latin Modern Roman the space before the superscript is ok:
[image]

However, when I load the `cmunrm` font, that space is littler, and the superscript' number is attached to the quotation mark, as you can see from the following image:
[image]

How can I increase the space with the `cmunrm` font as in the first example?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\MakeOuterQuote{"}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{cmunrm}

  
\begin{document}
Lorem "ipsum"\footnote{test} dolor sit amet, consectetur "adipiscing"\footnote{test} elit, 
sed "do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
Ut enim ad minim veniam"\footnote{test}, quis nostrud exercitation "ullamco"\footnote{test} laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
Duis "aute"\footnote{test} irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. 
"Excepteur sint"\footnote{test} occaecat cupidatat "non proident"\footnote{test}, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplified example:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\MakeOuterQuote{"}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily{\CMU}{CMU Serif}[Ligatures=TeX]

\begin{document}

"ipsum"\textsuperscript{1}

\CMU

"ipsum"\textsuperscript{1}

\showoutput

\end{document}
```

The relevant part with Latin Modern

```
....\TU/lmr/m/n/10.95 m
....\TU/lmr/m/n/10.95 ”
....\mathon
....\hbox(0.0+0.0)x0.0, direction TLT
....\hbox(5.32+0.0)x4.748, shifted -3.97366, direction TLT
.....\TU/lmr/m/n/8 1
....\mathoff
```

and with CMU

```
....\TU/CMUSerif(0)/m/n/10.95 m
....\TU/CMUSerif(0)/m/n/10.95 ”
....\mathon
....\hbox(0.0+0.0)x0.0, direction TLT
....\hbox(5.328+0.0)x4.5, shifted -3.97366, direction TLT
.....\TU/CMUSerif(0)/m/n/8 1
....\mathoff
```

so the problem is elsewhere. Indeed

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily{\CMU}{CMU Serif}[Ligatures=TeX]

\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\fboxrule}{0.1pt}

\begin{document}

\fbox{''}

\CMU

\fbox{''}

\end{document}
```

yields

[image]

so you see that the bounding box of the closing double quotes is very tight for CMU as compared to Latin Modern, which accounts for the (non)spacing you see.

You can “fix” it with a special quoting style.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{showframe}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\MakeOuterQuote{"}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily{\CMU}{CMU Serif}[Ligatures=TeX]

\DeclareQuoteStyle{CMU}% verified
  {\kern0.1em\relax\textquotedblleft\kern0.05em\relax}
  {\kern0.1em\relax\textquotedblright\kern0.05em\relax}
  [0.05em]
  {\textquoteleft}
  {\textquoteright}


\begin{document}

\noindent
"ipsum \enquote{lorem}\textsuperscript{1} ipsum"\textsuperscript{1} 

\CMU
\setquotestyle{CMU}

\noindent
"ipsum \enquote{lorem}\textsuperscript{1} ipsum"\textsuperscript{1}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I leave to you to adjust the spacings to suit your needs.

There may be LuaTeX methods for adjusting the faulty bounding boxes.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! Your code works perfectly with `\footnote`, but doesn't when I use instead `\footcite`. Is there a way to make sure that it works in both cases?

Comment: @Urel Sorry, but an example is lacking.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to change a line: it works like a charm also with `\footcite`. Thanks again!